# Using a tupel in WHERE clause of sqlite

Tags: sqlite, sql-delete, where-in

I have a table `t2` with coordinates and I want to delete all entries in `t1` that include those tupel of coordinates.

I'm looking for a command, which works like this.

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE (x,y) IN (SELECT x,y FROM t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Converting the tupel into a combined string works fine!!!

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE x||','||y IN (SELECT x||','||y FROM t2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM t1 WHERE (x,y) IN (SELECT x,y FROM t2);
```

This query works in SQLite 3.15.0 or later.